# Get nested table id by searching td text

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI i want to get nested table id based on text search.Please help me on this.

i want to get id="nested1" by searching text "PCI Date".

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table id="nested1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span>PCI Date</span></td>
<td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table id="nested2">
<tr>
<td><span>New text</span></td>
<td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried? rather than seeking an answer. So at what point do you want the id? what's the process?

Comment: `$('span:contains("PCI Date")').closest('table').attr('id')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `contains()` & `parents()`

```
var id = $('span:contains("PCI Date")').parents('table').attr('id');
alert(id);
```

**Reference:**

- [`contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)